# CSS Transition speed on off hover, strange transparency for flip pane?

Tags: html, css, animation, flip

I have a couple of div elements which I want to flip over on hover. A couple things I'm unsure how to do are:

1. Change the flip speed on off hover (when no longer hovering). I was able to change the flip speed to 0.5s duration on hover, but how do I change the off hover speed?
2. The front face and back face of the flippable pane has a background color. Why is it being treated as a transparent/glass background where you can see the reverse of the front? I don't want to see the front face mirrored + back face when I should only be able to see the back face.

Any tips?

edit; in case the transparency issue doesn't appear, here's an image of what I see.

[image]

The desired display is a solid color panel with "ipsum" and "something" on it. It shouldn't show the mirror image of the front face.

```css
.flip_container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 270px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.flip_container {
    perspective: 1000;
}
.flip_card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
.flip_container:hover .flip_card {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    font-family: tahoma, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
.face.front {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13pt;
    color: white;
}
.face.back {
    display: block;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
.imagebox {
    width: 260px;
    height: 160px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.imagebox img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.flip_card.purpleline {
    background-color: #BAADBA;
}
.flip_card.blueline {
    background-color: #ADB3BA;
}
.smaller {
    font-size: 11pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="flip_container">
    <div class="flip_card purpleline">
        <div class="front face">
            <div class="imagebox">
                <img src="http://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/pages/photo_latest14.jpg" />
            </div>
            cat
        </div>
        <div class="back face">
            ipsum
            <br/><br/>
            <span class="smaller">
                sometext
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flip_container">
    <div class="flip_card blueline">
        <div class="front face">
            <div class="imagebox">
                <img src="http://animalia-life.com/data_images/dog/dog7.jpg" />
            </div>
            dog
        </div>
        <div class="back face">
            lorem
            <br/><br/>
            <span class="smaller">
                sometext
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can change the `transition: all 1.0s linear` in `.flip-card` class to `transition: all 0.5s linear` to speed up the flip speed. I'm not able to replicate your issue #2 though. It looks fine on Chrome Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS does not support :mousein or :mouseout.

You can use :hover to add :mousein properties and the usual default class w/o the hover should have your :mouseout properties

Else you always have JS to do the trick.

```
$('#element').hover(function(e){
    if(e.type==='mouseenter' || e.type==='mouseover'){
        //your :mousein code
    }else if(e.type==='mouseleave'){
        //your :mouseout code
    }
});
```

Hope this answers your query.